# In PHP, I need to use a for loop to iterate the number of times specified by the user

Tags: php

I'm doing an assignment to replicate a page in which you input a number into a textbox and then the loop iterates that number of times (between 0 and 5). IE,

Input: 5

Output: 
Iteration is 1.
Iteration is 2.
Iteration is 3.
Iteration is 4.
Iteration is 5.

I'm using this:

```
<?php
    $rows = $_GET['rows'];
    for ($rows = 1; $rows <= 5; $rows++) {
        echo "Iteration is $rows <br />";
    }
?>
```

And my form looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="get">
   <p>Iterations:
       <input type="text" name="rows">
       <input type="submit" value="Loop">
   </p>
</form>
```

The code I am using is only returning the list 1-5 for any number I enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're resetting the variable in the loop. For the loop you have to use a different variable and then put the max limit up to your `$rows` variable.

```
<?php
   $rows = intval($_GET['rows']);   // Make sure its an integer
   for ( $i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++ ) {
      echo "Iteration is $i <br />";
   }
?>
```

**Credit:** Forcing `$rows` to be an integer in this answer was done after taking inspiration from the answer to same question by @nurakantech.

Comment: This worked! Thanks... I could see I was just telling it do to something in the range 0-5 but couldn't limit it to the user specified part.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$rows = $_GET['rows'];
for($i = 1; $i <= (int)$rows; $i++){
   echo "Iteration $i.<br>";
}
```

Comment: Good point on type casting to int

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
    // $rows[$i] <-- This holds your $rows data
}
```

Comment: `$rows` is not an array - iterating to `count($rows)` won't work.

Comment: Indeed, I had assume it was an array. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of `$rows` in your loop. You need to do something like this:

```
<?php
$rows = $_GET['rows'];
for ($x = 0; $x < $rows; $x++) {
  echo "Iteration is $x <br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In your loop use another variable name like :

```
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++){
   //manage stuff here
 }
```